# Method template.copy is not working - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am facing a problem that is leaving me without a real solution.
I want that the script create a new Google Doc copy from a template, then transfer data from Sheet toward the new Doc.

The script is running without a bug, but fail to create a copy of the document as it supposed to do.

```
function transferData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Tour de Contrôle");
  var templateId = "119ORijiWNQEdpG4KqjNCYzilbf_ob7SMdOPXUK3woMQ";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("166g1akWuHR3MtoDzbh9ydMhEpr4euCts");

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 3; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][12] === true) {
      var nom = data[i][3];
      var nFonction = data[i][6];

      var template = DocumentApp.openById(templateId);
      var newDoc = template.copy("Mouvement_" + nFonction + "_" + nom + "_EMBA");
      newDoc.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS).getFile().moveTo(folder);
      
      var docBody = newDoc.getBody();

      var matricule = data[i][4];
      var compta = data[i][16];
      var division = data[i][1];
      var fonction = data[i][6];
      var respDoss = sheet.getRange("GDD!B3").getValue();
      var endosGDD = sheet.getRange("GDD!B6").getValue();
      var sign = sheet.getRange("GDD!B7").getValue();

      docBody.replaceText("{Nom}", nom);
      docBody.replaceText("{Matricule}", matricule);
      docBody.replaceText("{NFonction}", nFonction);
      docBody.replaceText("{Compta}", compta);
      docBody.replaceText("{division}", division);
      docBody.replaceText("{Fonction}", fonction);
      docBody.replaceText("{RespDoss}", respDoss);
      docBody.replaceText("{EndosGDD}", endosGDD);
      docBody.replaceText("{Sign}", sign);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no DocumentApp.openById(templateId).copy() method. To make a copy of a doc you should use Driveapp instead.

You should change these lines of code

```
var template = DocumentApp.openById(templateId);
var newDoc = template.copy("Mouvement_" + nFonction + "_" + nom + "_EMBA");
newDoc.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS).getFile().moveTo(folder);
```

For these ones:

```
var template = DriveApp.openById(templateId);
var newDoc = template.makeCopy("Mouvement_" + nFonction + "_" + nom + "_EMBA", folder);
```

[makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)

With SpreadsheetApp you can make a copy of a spreadsheet but you can't choose the folder where it will be created (it's created in the same folder where your spreadsheet "file" is located).
[copy(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I modified `const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFolderById` by `const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById`

It worked.

Thanks for your help.

```
function transferData() {
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tour de Contrôle");
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('119ORijiWNQEdpG4KqjNCYzilbf_ob7SMdOPXUK3woMQ');
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('166g1akWuHR3MtoDzbh9ydMhEpr4euCts');

  const respDoss = sheet.getRange("GDD!B3").getValue();
  const endosGDD = sheet.getRange("GDD!B6").getValue();
  const sign = sheet.getRange("GDD!B7").getValue();
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //Logger.log(rows)

  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Generated date', if so we skip it
      //if (row[16] === true);
    //Here we check if the value in column Q (index 17) is true, if not we skip this row
    if (index >= 4) {
    if (row[17] !== true){
      return;
      }
    }
        Logger.log(rows);

    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Mouvement_${row[6]}, ${row[3]}_EMBA` , destinationFolder);
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
...
```