# Using Google Apps Script to detect a calendar event with a keyword to copy and rename a template file to the appropriate year and month subfolder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

In my various groups of friends, I tend to be the one that everyone looks to in order to organize and plan everything. Love doing it, but it definitely helps when I have some sort of document to work off of.

In the dummy example I have to share, I am planning a potluck with some friends. I want to create a calendar event for it, and when I enter `#potluck` in the event description, I want to be able to have the script take action by copying a template file I have specified, check the date of the event, and make the appropriate year and month folder (if they don't already exist), and copy the template file to that folder. Lastly, it renames the file to be "Potluck + event date" and replaces the `#potluck` from the event description to be a URL to the event's newly created template file.

Hopefully I phrased all of that clearly...

[Here is my code so far](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1Uj7NWgZ2MMp_tOaqb38irVbT83RSjlO2QeAfK2KbOcn2cp9TTpcdq-XE/edit).

Everything functions fine up until a  certain point.

```
// Confirms whether the event has the #potluck tag
let description = event.getDescription();
if (description.search('#potluck') == -1) continue;

  const eventDate = Utilities.formatDate(event.getStartTime(), "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");
  
  // Get the year from the event date
  const year = eventDate.split("-")[2];
  
  // Get the month number from the event date
  const monthNum = eventDate.split("-")[0];
  
  // Get the month name from the month number
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  const month = monthNames[parseInt(monthNum, 10) - 1];
```

The first section will check Google Calendar for any events with the event description `#potluck` and parses the date so it can create a year folder and month subfolder if they do not already exist.

```
  // Get the root folder
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1jdLNv-vG6RfijAHZaIvQdfSEwBEq-UIB");
  
  // Check if the year folder exists
  var yearFolder = rootFolder.getFoldersByName(year);
  if (yearFolder.hasNext()) {
    yearFolder = yearFolder.next();
  } else {
    // Create the year folder
    yearFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(year);
  }
  
  // Check if the month folder exists
  var monthFolder = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(month);
  if (monthFolder.hasNext()) {
    monthFolder = monthFolder.next();
  } else {
    // Create the month folder
    monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(month);
  }
```

**Where I seem to hit a snag is at line 72 when I have copied the file, renamed it, and created the year and month folders if they don't already exist. The script attempts to move the newly created file**

```
  var templateSheetId = "14IZEMR-fjgc8YvlgQJJCpyGotBJ3YqLTP87s38vWPaM";
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateSheetId);
  var newSheet = templateSheet.copy("Potluck " + eventDate);
    newSheet.moveTo(monthFolder);
```

For some reason, even though I believe I have followed [the syntax of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) around `moveTo()`, I am getting an error that reads:

> TypeError: newSheet.moveTo is not a function

Is there a different way I should be calling for this file to be moved? Is there a better way to relocate a file in Google Drive? As of now, it just creates it in my root Google Drive folder, but I cannot move it to `monthFolder` after that.

I tried using `moveTo()` to get the newly created file to move to the appropriate folder. When that did not work, I tried copying it there with `copy()` and `copyTo()` but both ran into a similar error. I looked at other functions like `move()` but they result in the same issue. I tried following some tutorials where they move a file and remove the original, but that creates an entirely different function for one simple step (or so I believe it to be).

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to Daniel for informing me of the differences between creating an object with `SpreadsheetApp` and `DriveApp`

My code was updated as follows:

```
    var templateSheet = DriveApp.getFileById("14IZEMR-fjgc8YvlgQJJCpyGotBJ3YqLTP87s38vWPaM");
    var newSheet = templateSheet.makeCopy("Potluck " + eventDate, monthFolder);
```

Comment: moveTo() is a DriveApp method not a SpreadsheetApp method.  [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425313/method-template-copy-is-not-working-google-script/75425410#75425410)

Comment: So if `SpreadsheetApp` cannot use `moveTo()` then it should be `DriveApp`? Is that right? So my lines in the 70s should be ` var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateSheetId);
  var newSheet = templateSheet.copy("Potluck " + eventDate);
    newSheet.moveTo(monthFolder);`

Or is that not accurate? I just changed `SpreadSheetApp` to `DriveApp.openById` as well as `DriveApp.getFilebyId` and got `is not a function` for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is because `newSheet` is a `Spreadsheet` object. If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) you can find a list of its methods. The Spreadsheet methods manipulate the spreadsheet data, but they are not in charge of moving the file within Drive. For this you need to create a [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object with [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). Example with your code:

```js
  var templateSheetId = "<ID>";
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateSheetId);
  var newSheet = templateSheet.copy("Potluck " + eventDate);
  
  var drivefile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheet.getId())
  drivefile.moveTo(monthFolder)
```

But I think the best way is to make the copy with `makeCopy()`, which allows you to set the name and location right away. If you don't need to manipulate the spreadsheet you can just avoid calling `SpreadsheetApp` unnecessarily, which is generally a good practice:

```js
  var templateSheetId = "<ID>"
  var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSheetId)
  copy.makeCopy("Potluck " + eventDate, monthFolder)
```

In conclusion, the problem was that you were using some methods with the wrong classes. I recommend you get acquainted with the documentation to see which methods belong to which classes, and what they return:

- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

Comment: Thank you. This was the articulate and informed response I was looking for. I was unaware that creating an object with `Spreadsheet` or `DriveApp` had such different abilities.